# React guard change the route but does not show the component

Tags: reactjs

Actually I created a first level guard named `PrivateRouteLogin` to prevent the user to go to the dashboard if did not log in already. 
The registration flow has 3 step that user cannot go forward if did not pass the previous step so I have created another guard to prevent user to go to second and third step if did not pass the previous step and the problem is when user goes to the second or third step the route has changed but nothing present in the view.

The first level file is:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Footer from '../containers/Footer'
import Landing from '../containers/Landing'
import Aml from '../components/investorOnboarding/Aml/index'
import Restricted from './Restricted';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import Login from './Login';
import Register from './Register';
import InvestorOnboarding from './InvestorOnboarding';
import SignicatCallBack from '../components/Auth/SignicatCallBack';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar'
import { PrivateRoute, PrivateRouteLogin } from './guards/PrivateRoutePresentation';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar/>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"><Landing/></Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard"><Dashboard/></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRouteLogin path="/login"><Login/></PrivateRouteLogin>
        <PrivateRouteLogin path="/register"><Register/></PrivateRouteLogin>
        <PrivateRouteLogin path="/onboarding/investor"><InvestorOnboarding/></PrivateRouteLogin>
        <PrivateRoute path="/aml"><Aml/></PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/restricted"><Restricted/></PrivateRoute>
        <Route path="/auth/callback"><SignicatCallBack/></Route>
      </Switch>

      <Footer/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

my guards file is :

```
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FIXURA_TOKEN_NAME } from '../../constants';

export function PrivateRoutePresentation({ children, isAuthorized, pathname, ...rest }) {
  debugger
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        isAuthorized ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname,
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}

export const PrivateRoute = connect(() => ({
  isAuthorized: !!localStorage.getItem(FIXURA_TOKEN_NAME),
  pathname: '/login'
}))(PrivateRoutePresentation);

export const PrivateRouteLogin = connect(() => ({
  isAuthorized: !!!localStorage.getItem(FIXURA_TOKEN_NAME),
  pathname: '/dashboard'
}))(PrivateRoutePresentation);

export const PrivateRouteRegister = connect(() => ({
  isAuthorized: false,
  pathname: '/register/identity-verification'
}))(PrivateRoutePresentation);
```

and the resgister routes are:

```
import BorrowerOnBoarding from '../containers/BorrowerOnBoarding/BorrowerOnBoarding'
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router'
import React from 'react'
import LoanRejection from '../components/borrowerOnboarding/components/LoanRejection'
import IdentityVerification from '../components/Auth/Register/IdentityVerification'
import TermsAndConditionsModal from '../components/Auth/Register/TermsAndConditionsModal'
import ProvideDetails from '../components/Auth/Register/ProvideDetails'
import VerifyPhoneNumber from '../components/Auth/Register/VerifyPhoneNumber'
import { PrivateRouteRegister } from './guards/PrivateRoutePresentation';

export default () => (
  <>
    <Route exact path="/register/legacy" component={BorrowerOnBoarding}/>
    <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterRedirect}/>
    <Route path="/register/identity-verification" component={IdentityVerificationView}/>
    <PrivateRouteRegister path="/register/provide-details"><ProvideDetails/></PrivateRouteRegister>
    <Route path="/register/verify-phone-number" component={VerifyPhoneNumber}/>
    <Route path="/register/reject" component={LoanRejection}/>
  </>
)

const RegisterRedirect = () => (
  <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/register/identity-verification' }}/>
)

const IdentityVerificationView = () => (
  <>
    <IdentityVerification/>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/register/identity-verification/terms-and-conditions"><TermsAndConditionsModal/></Route>
    </Switch>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems your private router doesn't render children component properly

```
 <Route
  {...rest}
  render={({ location }) =>
    isAuthorized ? (
      // following line doesnt return react node
      children
    ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname,
          state: { from: location }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
/>
```

try like this

```
 <Route
  {...rest}
  render={({ location }) =>
    isAuthorized ? (
      // you can pass some props what you need as second parameter
      React.createElement(children, rest)
    ) : (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname,
          state: { from: location }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
/>
```

and also following link will help you fix your problem
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func